# Android SDK & AVD Managers in Eclipse on Fedora 16 - no close window button

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I have installed Android SDK and all the associated Eclipse plugins, along with the GWT, which was required.  All the installation reported success.

However, when I go to either SDK Manager or AVD Manager, when the window pops up, it is missing a close window button and I have no way of closing it or going back to the Eclipse main. I must then find the Eclipse top-level PID with `ps aux | grep eclipse` and kill the process.

Update: I'm using GNOME-Shell.

Comment: I guess you are using GNOME-Shell……

Comment: Switched from GNOME to KDE desktop -- problem gone !! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem within GNOME.  Once I switched to KDE the problem was gone.